# Getting stable SOLR scores

Tags: solr, lucene

I run a query against a SOLR core and restrict the result using a filter
like `fq: {!frange l=0.7 }query($q)`. I'm aware that SOLR scores do not
have an absolute meaning, but the 0.7 (just an example) is calculated
based on user input and some heuristics, which works quite well.

The problem is the following: I update quite a few documents in my core.
The updated fields are only meta data fields, which are unrelated to the
above search. But because an update is internally a delete + insert, IDF
and doc counts change. And so do the calculated scores. Suddenly my
query returns different results.

As Yonik explained to me [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/heliosearch/achim/heliosearch/J0SzIPg1ffc/wdxhUxv6ca0J), this behaviour is by design. So my question is: What is the most simple
and minimal way to keep the scores and the output of my query stable?

Running optimize after each commit should solve the problem, but I
wonder if there is something simpler and less expensive.

Answer (score 2):

You really need to run optimize. When you optimize the index solr clean all documents not pointed yet and make the query stable. This occurs because build this meta data information is expensive to be done all the time a document is updated. Because of this solr just do that on optimize. There is a good way to see if your index is more or less stable... When you access Solr API you could see `Num Docs` and `Max Doc` information. If `Max Doc` is greater than `Num Docs` it seams that you have some old products affecting your relevancy calculation. Optimizing the index these two numbers is made equal again. If these numbers are equal you can trust IDF is been calculated correctly.